# Rename IdentityRole table in EF Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I'm having issues extending IdentityRole role in EF Core 3.  I want to rename the table and add a property but when I scaffold the table, it creates it as "IdentityRole" instead of the name I specify "ApplicationRole" and it does not scaffold the property I added.

In startup.cs

```
            services
            .AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

My classes.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("ApplicationUser");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("ApplicationRole");


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;

    [PersonalData]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

What gets scaffolded...

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "IdentityRole",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_IdentityRole", x => x.Id);
            });
```

UPDATED.  As others have suggested, I tried a different implementation that is in the Microsoft Docs as shown below

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
   
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>

services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
  .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
  .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Which leaves me with this mess of an error when I do the inital scaffold.

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
> services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Portal.Data.Entities.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Portal.Security.AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Portal.Data.Entities.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Portal.Security.AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Portal.Data.Entities.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Portal.Data.Entities.ApplicationUser]':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Portal.Security.AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Portal.Data.Entities.ApplicationUser]':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Portal.Security.AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Portal.Data.Entities.ApplicationUser]':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Portal.Security.AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Portal.Data.Entities.ApplicationUser]
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Portal.Data.Entities.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Portal.Security.AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Portal.Data.Entities.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Portal.Security.AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Portal.Security.AdditionalUserClaimsPrincipalFactory'.) Unable to
> create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different
> patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Comment: You can refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Tried a couple things in the official doc I was not doing but it still doesn't work and I'm getting the error "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'.".  Not sure why trying to name tables in my database the way I want to and add a couple custom properties is so hard.

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify the entity type for roles, you need to inherit from `IdentityDbContext<TUser,TRole,TKey>` instead of `IdentityDbContext<TUser>`, otherwise there's no way for the base `IdentityDbContext` to know what your role entity is.

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
```

Comment: I've tried that but I end up with an error when I scaffold -> "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'.

Comment: in startup.cs, did you try replacing `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` by `.AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()`?

Comment: Yes and I still get the error -> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'.